# How to determine the end of file in custom archive?

Tags: python, algorithm, archive

When I archive recursively a directory with files in Python with custom compression algorithm (e.g. *MyZip*), when I decompress archive to directory how I can get the end of file for decompress data?

Comment: Related: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: The design of the container structure/file holding the results of your custom  compression algorithm will need to provide this meta-information if the there's no way to detect EOF while decompressing the data.

Comment: @martineau Can you please provide possible algorithm, how i can implement this?

Comment: A common method used in files is to first have a variable-length header record that defines the starting offset and length of each item in the archive. Nested directories could be handled by having an flag for each item indicating whether it was for a file or another header for a sub-directory.